# Broken Vue CLI installation npm

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

after trying to update vue cli to its latest version using npm update, now everytime I run vue it throws the following error:

```
vue create
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'strip-ansi'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/logger.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/logger.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/logger.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v17.3.0
```

If I try to uninstall the package, I also get an error:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/.cli-kgOlUxFE
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/.cli-kgOlUxFE'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-17T17_58_23_457Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't know what to do, I need vue cli working

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the `node_modules` folder and install all dependencies again with `npm install`.

Comment: Would it be enough to just remove the `@vue` folder inside `node_modules`?

Comment: @JonPC it depends. Sometimes you have some wrong dependencies. Or you install first time with an other node version and and and. Better to remove the whole folder.